# Authenticate Azure .cer instead of client secret

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I registered my app in azure portal, and set up my certificate. My question is how do I authenticate a user using the .cer certificate. I don't want to use client secret in

Comment: Could you provide more details? What do you want to do with the AD App? e.g. access the azure resources? call the ms graph?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [python demo](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/certificate_credentials_sample.py) about how to use ADAL for authentication using certificate credentials. You could take a reference.